# Asynchronous Web Language

Tags: web, asynchronous-programming

I'm searching for a suitable way to make web requests to databases and display results in real-time. The data will be used in an interface for staff, so there cannot be any blocking or lag as time is a key factor.

So far, I've been using PHP for the backend of the system. However now that I've come to the interface, I'm slightly stuck.

I've used java (android) asynchronously before, and ideally am after a similar method of processing calls. From what I've read there is no current way of using php truly asynchronously.

**What** is a good web language to use for this purpose? or what are my available options?

Comment: what do you mean by "real-time". Real time is one concept (processing cannot take longer than x time), "non-blocking-ui" processing is a different one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you probably don't mean strong [real-time computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)!

Assuming you mean [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) you could use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) techniques (then [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) could help) to periodically (e.g. every 10 seconds) query some web server (that web server could itself query some database) from inside the browser.

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) itself is *synchronous*: each HTTP request gets one answer.

There is also [webservices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservice) and [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket)

Several languages and frameworks support all this quite well: not only PHP but also [Opa](http://opalang.org/) or Ocaml with [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/), or [HOP](http://hop.inria.fr/). You could also code in C, C++ or in Java with some good HTTP server library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/) (of course some Javascript code is needed on the browser side)

Your question is too broad to get a more precise answer. It seems that you need to learn more about web technologies. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is not perfect, but has several tutorials and you could find many others (e.g. some [HTML-5 tutorial](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/)...)